# Razor Html.Label produces a blank label

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is in a MVC 4 app.  Code looks as follows:

```html
<div id="example">
    
        @if (Model.Questionnaires != null && Model.Questionnaires.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Questionnaires)
            {
                @Html.Label(@item.Title)  
                <div class="demo-section">
                    @foreach (var question in item.Questions)
                    {
                        <label id="@question.QuestionId.ToString()">@question.Text</label> <br />
                        @Html.Label(@question.Text ) <br />
                    }
                </div>
                <br />
            }
        }
        else 
        {
            <p>No matching lists where found.</p>
        }
    
</div>
```

The resulting output look like this:

```html
<div id="example">

  <label for="Pharmacy_Technician">Pharmacy Technician</label>
  <div class="demo-section">
    <label id="e4a2a2c9-2647-674e-b9fa-ff0000785e25">At least 18 years of age</label>
    <br />
    <label for="At_least_18_years_of_age">At least 18 years of age</label>
    <br />
    <label id="16a3a2c9-2647-674e-b9fa-ff0000785e25">Have a high school diploma or GED</label>
    <br />
    <label for="Have_a_high_school_diploma_or_GED">Have a high school diploma or GED</label>
    <br />
    <label id="24a3a2c9-2647-674e-b9fa-ff0000785e25">Have completed a training program or have a minimum 12 months of pharmacy related experience within the last 36 months</label>
    <br />
    <label for="Have_completed_a_training_program_or_have_a_minimum_12_months_of_pharmacy_related_experience_within_the_last_36_months">Have completed a training program or have a minimum 12 months of pharmacy related experience within the last 36 months</label>
    <br />
  </div>
  <br />
  <label for="Phlebotomy_Technician">Phlebotomy Technician</label>
  <div class="demo-section">
    <label id="afa5a2c9-2647-674e-b9fa-ff0000785e25">* Have successfully completed a training program or one year of work experience within the field. There is no specific time frame a candidate must test within once the training or work experience eligibility requirement has been met.</label>
    <br />
    <label for=""></label>
    <br />
    <label id="68a5a2c9-2647-674e-b9fa-ff0000785e25">* Posess a High School Diploma, or the equivalent</label>
    <br />
    <label for="">* Posess a High School Diploma, or the equivalent</label>
    <br />
  </div>
  <br />

</div>


</div>
```

As you can see there is a blank label that the helper is creating.  I do not understand why the Helper is killing the value of the label text.

The other thing that I do not understand is why the for is being populate in the first set of question why the second one is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `LabelFor` helpers would be more appropriate, but, as it uses reflection to create the naming, a `foreach` loop does not provide an index context (so it does not know how to name them correctly).

Try using `for` loops instead with `LabelFor`:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Questionnaires.Count; i++)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(Model.Questionnaires[i])  
            <div class="demo-section">
                @foreach (var q = 0; q < item.Questions.Count; q++)
                {
                    <label id="@question.QuestionId.ToString()">@question.Text</label> <br />
                    @Html.LabelFor(@Model.Questionnaires[i].Questions[q]) <br />
                }
            </div>
            <br />
        }
```

*Apologies for any typos, as this was typed directly into the answer from memory, but you get the idea.*

Comment: I think your suggestion is an improvement on what I was attempting.  I am still running into some strange results.   So I changed the lablefor line into: @Html.LabelFor(qt => qt.Questionnaires[i].Questions[q].Text).  What it is print out though is the literal word 'Text' and not the value that should be in that parameter.

Comment: Never mind.  I needed to provide the provide the parameter for the label.  @Html.LabelFor(q => Model.Questions[i].Text, Model.Questions[i].Text)  Now I need to figure out how mark your answer as the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It has a star (*), try to replace the star with __ and run it again

Comment: Well that fixed the reason why the for was empty.  The label itself is still not coming up.  Which makes sense since you can't have that character in an attribute.  Still puzzling why the helper is not able to produce the label correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. The Html helper printed a blank string instead of my string variable.

The reaseon was that the variable string held special characters in it, such as ".".

To solve the issue, I simply had to repeat the variable call as second parameter :

```
if(myConditionIsTrue){
    @Html.Label(myObj.myString, myObj.myString)
}
```